# Error while building Unity 8: "Could not determine USS private plugin installation dir."

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiling, unity8

I am going through [the steps to build Unity 8](https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/) and when I get to

```
$ ./build
```

it fails with this error

```
Could not determine USS private plugin installation dir.
```

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that I bring bad news. This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1431328) since 2015-03-12. [Login](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1431328/+login) with your Launchpad Account and click [This bug affects 2 people. Does this bug affect you?](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1431328/+affectsmetoo). So you will be informed about the progress.

Comment: I can't, it says I need 15 reputation...